# Unknown tags in a *.tag file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="u-p" tagdir='/WEB-INF/tags/user/parts' %>

<p><strong>Test</strong></p>
```

In eclipse it underlines both the

```
<p>
```

and the

```
<strong>
```

and marks them as errors.

Comment: You know... questions usually have a `?` in them somewhere.

Comment: Sorry I put in the tags and it showed the line as blank

Comment: Eclipse is a jerk when it comes to JSP validation. Ignore and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Strong is exactly the same thing as `<b>`, although I think speech reading software will use emphasis if they come across a `<strong>` tag.